# convert epoch number to readable date in html

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have an issue with Stripe Invoices in my Angular App.

The payment created field is populating in Firestore as a number and not a timestamp.

Short of editing the field each time an invoice is created or paid, is there a way to convert the number to a Firestore timestamp?

I've tried in html:

```
{{ created.toDate() | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' }}
```

I have contacted Stripe, but they had no idea what i was asking them to fix.

Comment: Could you kindly provide a sample timestamp? It would be quite helpful.

Comment: "*The payment created field is populating in Firestore as a number and not a timestamp.*" - certainly you have control over this code that's writing to your database and can share it in your post so we can see what's going on.  On Stack Overflow, it's important to provide a [complete, minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're doing so we can duplicate the behavior you observe.

Comment: Unfortunately not so easy to get the code from Stripe. They wrote the extension for Firebase.
The timestamps is this, 1651140588 and is stored in Firestore as a number, not a timestamp.
How can i convert this number to a readable date?